# How to implement nested ng-content with DI support?

Tags: angular

`ng-content` seems to define DI on where components were defined, not where components were rendered in run time. The behavior seems to be by design, and helpful for reusing external libraries.

Then what should I do if I need to get DI work on runtime?

```js
import { Component, Input, Optional, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WrapComponent } from './wrap.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'inner',
  template: `<div>Inner component {{ data }}, got wrap: {{ wrap !== null }}</div>`,
})
export class InnerComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() data: string;
  constructor(@Optional() private wrap: WrapComponent){
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.data)
  }
}
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wrap',
  template: `<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>`,
})
export class WrapComponent  {
}
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'outer',
  template: `<wrap><ng-content></ng-content></wrap>`,
})
export class OuterComponent  {
}
```

thus let inner component got wrap component injection when `app.html` is

```html
<outer> <inner></inner> </outer>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-ng-content-demo)

Comment: You can't get the WrapComponent via the DI this way. There are alternatives such as injecting OuterComponent and accessing a `@ViewChild()` property, or use `exportAs` on OuterComponent and pass wrap to an `@Input()` on InnerComponent.